# How i render a whole html through app-root?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7. I want to know that in index.html there is a whole html with app-root component middle of body. 
I want to know that if there is only app-root and nothing else written there. how i can render whole html page through this app route.?

Comment: Style app.component.html so it takes up 100% of the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is your question, but when an angular app is loaded in the browser, the index.html is served as the main page as usual, but what is displayed is what is in the app-root.html component. So if you view source, it will only show:

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

which is the content from the app-root.html component.